# htaccess error with symbol =

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've a  problem with an `htaccess redirect`.

In my `Google Search Console` I've found this link

http://www.example.com/index.php?id=10&L=2%27%2520AnD%25201%253D1--

that return error 403.

`"index.php"` doesn't exists in my website and I want write a rule that redirect this link to homepage.

The problem (in my opinion) it's that in this url there is a symbol `"="` without an `"*&var*"` before.

The decoded version of the url is

http://www.example.com/index.php?id=10&L=2' AnD 1=1--

If I remove (manually) the symbol `"="` (or it's encoded version `"*%253D*"`)  my `htaccess` woks perfectly.

Thanks
Lorenzo

`**ADD NEW DETAILS**`

OK, for url that has `1=1` it's probably `sql-injection`
But i've found also link as

http://www.example.com/index.php?eID=tx_cms_showpic&file=uploads%252Fpics%252FIMG_5213.jpg&width=800m&height=600m&bodyTag=%253Cbody%2520style%253D%2522margin%253A0%253B%2520background%253A%2523fff%253B%2522%253E&wrap=%253Ca%2520href%253D%2522javascript%253Aclose()%253B%2522%253E%2520%257C%2520%253C%252Fa%253E&md5=edc3c713d0e239f8a7e786cf52f29774

that decoded is

http://www.garnicristin.com/index.php?eID=tx_cms_showpic&file=uploads/pics/IMG_5213.jpg&width=800m&height=600m&bodyTag=&wrap= | &md5=edc3c713d0e239f8a7e786cf52f29774

I'm not shure that is older version of website (I not made older version) and the problem is the same, symbol `=` in url

Comment: I know that is a possible attack but I've not an sql connection in this website.
It's all static with json file attached.
Old website is 
http://example.it and I redirect all request to http://example.com

I've found this link beacuse google advise me that there are too 403 error. And the request is made by myexample.it (I'm not able to manage this site, it's not mine).
Then I would like to redirect this request with my htaccess

Comment: I see. Given that it seems to be a security module at play here,  you may have to talk to the server administrator to have it turned off, or do that redirect you want.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot.
I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AnD 1=1-
```

This looks like a lame attempt at a [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. The fact that your server returned a 403 ("Forbidden") error might mean that a security module in your web server detected the attempt, and served the error.

In that case, I would not add a rule trying to cater to these requests.

Comment: Ok, thanks.
Google does apply a penalty to my website, in your opinion?

Comment: Seems unlikely to me.

Comment: I've added new detail to the questions.